# Replace the first occurrence of an element in the list with 100 if it is present in the list

Tags: python, list

Replace the first occurrence of an element in the list with 100 if it is present in the list.Here is my code:

```
def replace_list(my_list,k):
    for count,item in enumerate(my_list):
        if item==k:
            print("found")
            my_list[count]=100
            break
    print(my_list)

my_list = [2,3,5]

k=int(input("Enter the number of elements"))
for n in range(0,k):
e=input()
my_list.append(e)
k=int(input("Enter the element to be removed"))
replace_list(my_list,k)
```

It's not working if we accept the list from the user. Instead, if I pass the list as a predefined one it works.

```
replace_list([2,3,5],k)
```

Comment: Next time, please also provide the error you received, as well as the stacktrace so we can better understand what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to cast input e to an integer. Hence, your array will be a list of strings instead of numbers.

Replace line 11 with

```
e = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your `e = input()` is receiving a string representation of a list, rather than a list. Like this:

```py
“[2, 3, 5]”
```

Since you want to iterate over a list, you need to turn this string into a Python list. You can do so by adding:

```py
# This will convert a string representation of a list into a Python list. For example, “[2, 3, 5]” will convert into a Python list [2, 3, 5]
my_list = e.strip('][').split(', ')
```

This is assuming you’re expecting input in the form: `[2, 3, 5]`
If you’re just expecting input in the form: `2 3 5` or `2,3,5`, it will be a little simpler:

```py
# This will convert a string of values separated by spaces or commas into a Python list. For example, “2 3 5” will convert into a Python list [2, 3, 5]
my_list = e.split()
```